# SQL JOIN Tables and display 3 categories of results

Tags: sql, select, join

Display results into 3 categories

```
create table test
(
    Type varchar(10),
    CheckFlag varchar(10),
    ID varchar(10)
)

Insert into test
values
('A','Yes','1'),
('A','Yes','2'),
('A','No','5'),
('A','No','6'),
('A','No','7'),
('B','Yes','8'),
('B','No','8'),
('B','No','9'),
('C','Yes','10'),
('C','Yes','11'),
('C','Yes','12'),
('C','No','10'),
('C','No','11'),
('C','No','12'),
('D','Yes','13'),
('D','Yes','14'),
('D','Yes','17'),
('D','No','14'),
('D','No','15'),
('D','No','16'),
('E','Yes','18'),
('E','Yes','19'),
('E','No','20'),
('E','No','21')

select    distinct T1.Type
          ,case when count(*) = count(T2.ID)
then      'In'
else 
           'Using in and out'
end 
from       test T1
left join  (select * from test
where      CheckFlag= 'No') T2 
on         T1.Type= T2.Type
and        T1.ID = T2.ID
Where      T1.CheckFlag= 'Yes'
group by   T1.Type
```

Expected Output:

```
Type      Category 
A         Out 
B         In
C         In
D         Out & In
E         Out
```

Here is the existing logic, Category for B,C & D is correct, however A & E are not accurate. Goal here is to show for every Type such as A,B,C,D,E every ID for a checkflag Yes is present in every DI for a checkflag No.

For Example,

1. For Type A,  Yes ID values are 1,2 and No ID values are 5,6. Since
   none of the Yes ID 1,2 is present in NO id 5,6. Assign Category
   "Out".
2. For Type D, Yes - ID are 13,14,17 & No - ID are 14,15,16. Here 14
   from yes is present in No ID- Assign Category "out and in"
3. For Example, Type B, Yes ID is 8 & No ID are 8,9. Since Yes ID
   8 is present in No ID then Assign "In".
4. For Example, Type C. Yes -
   ID - 10,11,12 & No  - ID - 10,11,12. All Yes IDs are present in No
   ID then Assign "In".

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself.

Comment: Since you don't explain where these `out`, `in`, and `out & in` values are coming from: `SELECT TYPE, CASE FLOOR(RAND()*(3-1+1))+1  WHEN  1 THEN 'Out' WHEN 2 THEN 'IN' WHEN 3 THEN 'Out & In' END as category FROM test GROUP BY type;`

Comment: @Marusyk i have provide the code above.

Comment: @JNevill In and Out logic depends on if for a particular type, checkfalg "Yes" had all the ID present in "No" ID. I have updated the question with more explanation. Also, this is dummy data. I will have additional "Types" and "ID" associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.

When NONE of the "Yes"es are in the "No"s, you want "OUT". That's:

```
 WHEN COUNT(T2.ID) = 0 THEN 'OUT'
```

When some - but not all - of the "Yes"es are in the "No"s, you want "OUT & IN". That's:

```
 WHEN COUNT(T2.ID) > 0 AND COUNT (T2.ID) < COUNT(*) THEN "OUT & IN"
```

When All of the "Yes"es are in the "No"s, you want "IN". That's everything else:

```
 ELSE 'In'
```

Comment: @rachel the best way to say thank  you on SO is to accept the answer :)

Comment: Done. Thanks @RadimBača